# Trying to understand Monads. The >> Operator

Tags: haskell, monads, operator-keyword

I'm new to haskell and I'm learning through LearnYouAHaskell. I just can't understand the reason behind the `(>>)` operator. 
The default implementation is:

```
(>>) :: (Monad m) => m a -> m b -> m b  
m >> n = m >>= \_ -> n
```

Which is (as far as I understand) ignores the first value and returns the second one. However, from the example in LearnYouAHaskell this happens:

> ghci> Nothing >> Just 3
>   Nothing
>   ghci> Just 3 >> Nothing
>   Nothing

So it *doesn't* ignores the first value. Yet, from a little research I found this quote from [here](http://haskelle.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/haskell-binding-operator-introduction.html)

> The >> function binding operator ignores the value of its first action
>   and returns as an overall result the result of its second action only.

So I'm **puzzled** about the usage of this operator and I want to ask 2 things:

1. *What* does it actually do?
2. *When* is it useful?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `>>` function only ignores the result of the first value but it **doesn't** ignore the side effect of the first value. To understand your example, see how `Maybe` Monad is defined:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
  return = Just
  (Just x) >>= f = f x
  Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
```

And `>>` function is defined like this:

```
m >> k      = m >>= \_ -> k
```

`Nothing >> _` will produce `Nothing` according to the definition of `Maybe` monad. In your second example `Just 3 >> Nothing` gets expanded to `Just 3 >>= \_ -> Nothing` and produces `Nothing`. To give you an example of how it only ignores the value of the first action but doesn't ignore the side effect, consider the following example:

```
λ> print 3 >> print 4
3
4
```

You can see in the above example, that although it ignores the result of `print 3` which is `()` but it doesn't ignore the side effect of it which is to display `3` to the screen.

`>>` function becomes useful once you start using other Haskell libraries. Two places where I use them occasionally is when dealing with Parsers (parsec, attoparsec) and Pipes library.

Answer (score 8):

It ignores the value of the first action, not the action itself.

```
Just 3 >> Just 5
```

The value of the action `Just 3` is `3`. It is being ignored in the `\_ -> n` part. The overall result is `Just 5`.

```
Just 3 >> Nothing
```

The value of the action `Just 3` is `3`. It is being ignored in the `\_ -> n` part. The overall result is `Nothing`.

```
Nothing >> Just 3
```

The action `Nothing` does not produce any value at all. What does it pass to the right operand of `>>=` (or `>>`) then? It doesn't! `>>=` for the `Maybe` monad is built such that if the left action is `Nothing`, the right action is not executed at all, and the overall result is `Nothing`.

Answer (score 7):

To complete Sibi answer `>>` can be seen as the `;` in other languages like C or C++..

When you do in C (or equivalent in other language)

printf("foo");
   printf("bar");

You obviously print `foobar` (the side effect) but those calls to `printf` also have a return value, which in our case is the length being printed ie 3 3. Have you ever wonder what happen to those numbers ?
They get ditched, because in C, *expr 1; exp 2*, means

- evaluate *expr1*
- ditch its result
- evaluate *expr2*

(At that point, you could ask yoursef why should the compiler bother evaluating *expr1* if it's to discard its result ? Because of the side effect. In the case of `printf` the side effect is to print something. You are rarely interested in the returned value itself.)

So `;` can be seen as an operator taking 2 expression and returning a new one. This is exactly the same as what the `>>` operator do.

When you write

```
 print "foo" >> print "bar"
```

it's exactly equivalent to `printf("foo");printf("bar")` except (and that's a major difference) `>>` is not something magic like `;` in C. `>>` it's a user defined operator and can be redefined for each type of Monad.
This is why Haskell programmers love Monad so much : In short, it allows you to redefine your own the behavior of `;`.

As we seen, in C `;` just evaluate an expression and discard it's value. In fact, it's bit more complicated because it doesn't if it's a `break` or a `return`. The Nothing in the Maybe monad could be seen as a `break` or a `return`. `>>` evaluates the first expression, and stop if it's `Nothing`. Otherwise it discards it's value and carry on.

You first example can be seen in `C` (I think it's valid C)

```
3; return
```

and

```
return; 3
```

The first example, compute `3`, discard its value and returns.
The second, returns straight away.

To answer you question `when is it usefull` ? Pretty much all the time when you are using IO, even though you rarely see it.

Instead of writing

```
 print "foo" >> print "bar"
```

Haskell provides a syntaxic sugar which transforms (pretty much) newlines to `>>` via the do-notation,
so you'll write

```
do
  print "foo"
  print "bar"
```

which is strictly equivalent to the former version (It fact the do notation version is transformed to the previous one by the compiler).

It is even also equivalent to (even though rarely used)

```
do print "foo"; print "bar"
```

To summarize, `>>` can be seen as an equivalent to `;` or newline is other languages with the difference that it's exact meaning depends on the *context* (which Monad is acting on).
`>>` in a Maybe monad is different from `>>` in a IO Monad.

Answer (score 3):

First of all let's clear your confusion on `Maybe` monad. Consider the following

```
instance Monad Maybe where
  return = Just
  (Just x) >>= g = g x
  Nothing  >>= _ = Nothing
```

As you can see by definition, `Nothing >>= _` is `Nothing`. Since `>>` is just a special case of `>>=` where the parameter is ignored, the result is the same.

This is because  `Maybe`s are usually used to represent computation that might fail. This is to tell us that "Once you fail, you are always fail".

Now to answer your questions.

1. The quote you mentioned already answer it.
2. It is useful in some situations where the result of the action is just not needed. For instance, the result of `putStrLn` is `()`, which is neither interesting nor can be useful in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple: simple words there are two operations needed for monad implementation:

- `>>=`
- `>>`

The first executes action and pass it's result of action to another action. For example:

```
Prelude> :t getLine
getLine :: IO String
Prelude> :t putStrLn
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

Two functions: first `getLine` just return String wrapped with `IO`, it reads string from `stdin` and wrapped it to IO. Second `putStrLn` gets `String` and prints it. Bind has following type:

```
:t (>>=)
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

It can be represented as `IO String -> (String -> IO String) -> IO String`, so you can combine this two or more functions with (>>=) by executing `getLine` and pass result `String` to the `putStrLn`:

```
getLine >>= putStrLn
```

So you can combine this two or more functions in one action.

The second `>>` produces almost the same, but it no need in result of previous action.

```
:t (>>)
(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
```

It just executes, first action, and than second, and second action is no need in result of first action:

```
putStrLn "Hello" >> putStrLn "World"
```